# Аналог команды :t из интерактивного режима ghci

Tags: haskell

В учебнике по haskell есть [раздел](http://learnyouahaskell.com/types-and-typeclasses#believe-the-type) посвящённый типам и показана удобная команда :t которой можно посмотреть тип выражений и функций:

```
ghci> :t 'a'  
'a' :: Char  
ghci> :t True  
True :: Bool  
ghci> :t "HELLO!"  
"HELLO!" :: [Char]  
ghci> :t (True, 'a')  
(True, 'a') :: (Bool, Char)  
ghci> :t 4 == 5  
4 == 5 :: Bool
```

Поскольку читая текст я тут же пытаюсь всё это выполнить, то я пошёл на ideone.com (к сожалению у меня пока нет возможности поставить локально среду выполнения haskell на своей машине) и написал примерно то же самое:

```
main = do
    putStrLn "Start"
    :t 'a'
    putStrLn "Finish"
```

Это не работает, выдаёт ошибку:

```
Compilation error   #stdin compilation error #stdout 0s 0KB

[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( prog.hs, prog.o )

prog.hs:1:5: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘IO t0’ with actual type ‘[IO ()]’
    • In the expression: main
      When checking the type of the IO action ‘main’
  |
1 |     main = do
  |     ^

prog.hs:3:10: error:
    Variable not in scope:
      t :: Char -> (String -> IO ()) -> [Char] -> [IO ()]
  |
3 |         :t 'a'
  |          ^
```

Аналогично не работает и простое:

```
:t 'a'
```

выдаёт ошибку:

```
Compilation error   #stdin compilation error #stdout 0s 0KB

[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( prog.hs, prog.o )

prog.hs:1:1: error: parse error on input ‘:’
  |
1 | :t 'a'
  | ^
```

Пробовал также через `putStrLn ("Finish" ++ show :t 'a')` -- тоже не работает.

Подскажите, есть ли какая-то возможность в онлайн-редакторах использовать :t или это возможно только при локальной установке среды haskell и работе с интерактивным режимом через gchi?

Возможно, это не умеет ideone.com но умеют какие-то другие онлайн-ресурсы?

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/68428366/5752652

Comment: https://replit.com/languages/haskell в правом окне набрать `ghci` и нажать `Enter`.

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать [**`typeOf :: forall a. Typeable a => a -> TypeRep`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Data-Typeable.html#v:typeOf) для получения объекта `TypeRep`.

Например:

```
import Data.Typeable(typeOf)

main = putStrLn ("Finish" ++ show (typeOf 'a'))
```

К сожалению, подобный подход не сработает с функциями.

<sub>Свободный перевод ответа https://stackoverflow.com/a/68428405/5752652 от участника  [@Willem Van Onsem](https://stackoverflow.com/users/67579/willem-van-onsem).</sub>

Comment: Не сработает не только (и не обязательно) с функциями, но и с любыми полиморфными значениями, для которых не получится вывести принадлежность классу типов `Typeable`. `typeOf not` сработает (потому, что конкретный тип `Bool -> Bool`), `typeOf 0` - нет (потому, что из `Num a => a` не следует `Typeable a => a`). Конечно такое себе решение вопроса, но вместо ideone можно воспользоваться repl.it, там есть консоль.

Answer (score 1):

Вы пытаетесь вставить команду интерактивной среды в исходный код своей программы. Это, закономерно, не срабатывает.

Попробуйте вместо `ideone` использовать сервис `repl.it`. Там можно в правой панели запустить интерактивную среду командой `ghci`, а уже в ней использовать и команду `:t` и прочие её возможности.